# Compress only files in a folder excluding the folders in the file's absolute path

Tags: command-line, find

I want to compress a folder with 100 files in batches of 10. I used the following script to do this. But what happens is when I unzip the gzipped file, it has all the folders from /.

```
find /home/ubuntu/reports/tmp -type f -print0 | split -t '\0' -l 5 -d --filter 'tar czf /home/ubuntu/reports/tmp/reports-$(date +"%F-%T")-$FILE.tar.gz --files-from=- --null'
```

Can anyone please tell me how to zip only the files without the containing folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to simply `cd` to the directory and run `find` from there:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/reports/tmp
find . -type f -print0 | split -t '\0' -l 5 -d --filter 'tar czf /home/ubuntu/reports/tmp/reports-$(date +"%F-%T")-$FILE.tar.gz --files-from=- --null'
```

Note that you're creating the tar.gz files in the same directory as the files, which means they will come up in `find`'s output and then get included in *other* tar.gz files. Put the tar.gz files in some other directory.

Also, for batches of 10, you need `-l 10`, not `-l 5`, which would be batches of 5.

Comment: Thank you and it worked! And, the files will be deleted once it is transferred to a backup location. So, they will not be included while using find. Thanks, again.

Comment: You were warned.

Comment: I was just mentioning a random number. I have changed it to 500 to match my case. Thanks!